# Printing variable with double quotes in AWK

Tags: printing, awk

I have the following awk code:

```
ip addr | grep -v '1: lo:' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | awk '/^[0-9]+:/ {sub(/:/,"",$2); iface=$2 } /^[[:space:]]*link\/ether / {mac=$2} /^[[:space:]]*inet / {split($2, if_arr, "/"); print iface "," if_arr[1] "," mac}'
```

It outputs like this:

```
eth0,10.53.55.22,00:51:56:9g:2f:e2
```

But I need output like this (in double quotes):

```
"eth0","10.53.55.22","00:51:56:9g:2f:e2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the print statement from

```
print iface "," if_arr[1] "," mac
```

to

```
print "\"" iface "\",\"" if_arr[1] "\",\"" mac "\""
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set/use `OFS` and you don't need to use grep if you're already using awk:

```
ip addr |
awk -v OFS='","' '/1: lo:|127.0.0.1/{next} /^[0-9]+:/... print "\"" iface, if_arr[1], mac "\""}'
```

You should probably be escaping each `.` in `127.0.0.1` though, whatever tool you use.